# How to format scientific data into proper data series for graph display in Ruby (Rails 3.1.x)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, graph

Needing some guidance about how to properly graph data that is very small and stored as BigDecimal.

If anyone has had experience using BigDecimals in any graphing scenario I believe your input on how you placed these into a usable sequence would be invaluable.

Presently I'm using [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) and it really seems that this is going to work out exceptionally well, however I've run into a hitch where I've not dealt with data on the minute BigDecimal scale hitherto.

Given my queries, I'll be pulling out about a 1,000 data points for a few different series of data ranging in accuracy from about 0.100E-9 to about 0.100E-1.

What would be the best way to prep these data series for presentation in such a graph that has a scientific application and therefore precision is important?  I'm not sure if I could or should continue in BigDecimal or something else?

---

I'm presently querying the database with a line similar to:

```
series_a = dataset.order("date").select('data_set.data1').limit(1000).all.zip
```

I'd appreciate some guidance of going from this result (again, the output is an array of BigDecimals) to the appropriate format for what will go into the chart series.

An contextual example of the code I'm using to build the chart in my controller is:

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  series_a = dataset.order("date").select('data_set.data1').limit(1000).all.zip
  series_b = dataset.order("date").select('data_set.data3').limit(1000).all.zip

  f.series(:name => 'Data 1', :data => series_a)
  f.series(:name => 'Data 2', :data => series_b)

  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => "line" })
  f.yAxis [
        {:title => { :text => "Left Y Label", :margin => 10} },
        {:title => { :text => "Right Y Label"}, :opposite => true }
  ]
  f.xAxis(:title => { :text => "X Label"} )
  f.title(:text => "Graph Title")
  f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 75, :x => -50, :layout => 'vertical')
end
```

---

I think I'm a bit further along in my understanding of this having decided to convert the BigDecimals to strings as per "[How to access fields by attribute name from ActiveRecord row results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782699/how-to-access-fields-by-attribute-name-from-activerecord-row-results/8782778#8782778)" However it appears ultimately this fails and gives erratic results as the series functions `:data` field expects, I think, numeric input.  I am thinking that this ultimately emits json to highcharts, however I'm still stuck for the moment in my attempt to pass these values on in correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
series_a = dataset.order("date").select('data_set.data1').limit(1000).all.zip
```

you'll end up with an array of arrays as we already discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782778/479863). If you get rid of the `zip`, you should end up with an array of objects in `series_a`. I'd guess that chart would be happier with an array of numbers so:

```
series_a = dataset.order("date").
                   select('data_set.data1').
                   limit(1000).
                   all.
                   map(&:data1)
```

or, if `data1` is a BigDecimal (due to using a fixed precision type in the database) then maybe you'd want this:

```
series_a = dataset.order("date").
                   select('data_set.data1').
                   limit(1000).
                   all.
                   map { |o| o.data1.to_f }
```

to get an array of floating point values that the chart should know what to do with.

I'm not familiar with Highcharts so there is some guesswork here.

Comment: Yes, the `.zip` was already gone. Forgot to drop that off of the above example.  What I'm struggling with is that it appears to want a numeric value vs a string, yes.  I think the to_f is the key, although in my exercises so far I keep getting a `stack level too deep` at each angle.  Will now attempt your suggestion.

Comment: So far I'm dickering with this: http://pastebin.com/MZFWbrcn - I'm not really seeing why it wouldn't work in that I would save a query since I'm pulling out two data points.  I could do two with a do block as well with yours obviously, but still... Not quite seeing my issue.

Comment: Well, I am presently screwed.  Even testing with a simple `puts "100".to_f.to_s` is failing with the same error.

Comment: @ylluminate: Looks like all that should work fine. What happens if you manually put an `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 11.0]` array? Or can it only handle integers (which would be rather silly)? Try `[1, 2, 3, 11]` or `to_i` and see what happens.

Comment: No, any numeric works fine.  The problem appears to only be in rails in that controller, however I just did a `bundle update` which updated kgio from 2.7.0 to 2.7.2 and I initially thought the error went away.  It loaded up.  If I keep it at about 5 records from the database, I end up seeing it load up roughly 25% of the time on refreshes.  If I increase that to 10 records, for example, it fails every time with that stack error.  :\

Comment: Only other info I'm seeing in this error on the full trace is: "actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73"

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace anywhere?

Comment: Well, I could not get a full stack trace of this for the life of me, however I was able to trace it back to a convenience to_s that was added to Float back many months ago for the project.  It's now working 100% of the time, however I have some points in time where values are non existent and I have to try to figure out how to not plot data at these points in time... but yes!  At least it's populating the data now.  Just a little concerned about BigDecimal -> Float in terms of precision, yet a direct conversion may be alright as long as I'm not evoking arithmetic on the values, right?

Comment: You're probably getting BigDecimal out of the database because you used a `decimal(m,n)` column. With the range you're working with I don't think the `to_f` conversion will cause any problems for a chart.

Comment: Thanks this is to be a highly accurate chart, but so far I think you're right.