# How to access fields by attribute name from ActiveRecord row results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Apparently I'm missing something obvious here, but would appreciate a quick example.

I've got a record coming back from ActiveRecord where I have a few columns selected from a query.  The fields are of BigDecimal format and need to be flattened to string.

I had initially thought it was sufficient to pull the query with:

```
rows = ModelName.order("date DESC").select('table_name.precise_number1, table_name.precise_number2').limit(100).all.zip
rows_stringified1 = Array.new
rows_stringified2 = Array.new

readings.each do |row|
  rows_stringified1.push row[:precise_number1].to_s
  rows_stringified2.push row[:precise_number2].to_s
end
```

However, this yields an error such as `can't convert Symbol into Integer`.  Obviously I'm not following exactly how to access columns from records in a row set result.

How would you normally do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have a typo and you're doing this:

```
readings = ModelName.order("date DESC").
                     select('table_name.precise_number1, table_name.precise_number2').
                     limit(100).
                     all.
                     zip
```

instead of assigning to `rows`. Noticed that [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) at the end? That doesn't make any sense. When you do this:

```
[a, b, c].zip
```

you get this:

```
[[a], [b], [c]]
```

So, in your `readings.each` block, the `row` is in fact `[model]` rather than the `model` that you think it is and that means that `row[:precise_number1]` is trying to access the *Array* `row` using the Symbol `:precise_number1` instead of the Integer that the Array expects, hence your "can't convert Symbol into Integer" error.

So either get rid of the `zip` and leave your `each` as-is:

```
readings = ModelName.order("date DESC").
                     select('table_name.precise_number1, table_name.precise_number2').
                     limit(100).
                     all
# ...
readings.each do |row|
  rows_stringified1.push row[:precise_number1].to_s
  rows_stringified2.push row[:precise_number2].to_s
end
```

or keep the `zip` and adjust your `each` block to match what `row` really looks like:

```
readings = ModelName.order("date DESC").
                     select('table_name.precise_number1, table_name.precise_number2').
                     limit(100).
                     all.
                     zip
# ...
readings.each do |row|
  rows_stringified1.push row.first[:precise_number1].to_s
  rows_stringified2.push row.first[:precise_number2].to_s
end
```

I'd recommend getting rid of the `zip` as it does nothing useful and just confuses things.

Comment: Yes, I had unthinkingly left the zip method in from an example I'd followed. I would be immensely curious and appreciative if you could take a look at the following as this was an intermediate, but unfruitful, step in this ultimate problem: [How to format scientific data into proper data series for graph display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754486/how-to-format-scientific-data-into-proper-data-series-for-graph-display-in-ruby)